# meteor - get value from child to parent

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

**What I'm trying to achieve:** Get data from a nested element.

**How I tried to achieve it:** Use `ref` attribute of a child to get that element in the parent. Doesn't work because `this.refs` appears to only contain `refs` in the top component, not nested components.

`SubmitStoryForm.jsx` has nested component `TextInput.jsx`, which is a simple `<input />` component.

So I have two elements in my form, `SubmitStoryForm.jsx`:

```
<TextInput label="Story name" refer="titleInput" />
<textarea className="materialize-textarea" ref="bodyInput" />
```

The `refer` attribute is what is put into the `ref` attribute in `TextInput`:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes,} from 'react';

export default class TextInput extends Component {
  render() {
    const refer = this.props.refer;
    console.log(refer);
    const id = 'id_'+refer;
    const type = this.props.type;
    const col = this.props.col;
    const label = this.props.label;
    return (
      <div className=
        {col ? 'input-field col ' + col : 'input-field col s3'}>
          <input
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            id={id}
            ref={refer}
            type={type ? type : 'text'} />
          {label ?
            <label for={id}>
              {this.props.label}
            </label> : ''}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

TextInput.propTypes = {
  refer: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Works fine for the `textarea` element because the `ref` attribute is defined in the parent. But when I pass that responsibility to a child, `TextInput`, `ref` is not available.

Is this how I should structure my code?

The code fails when I try to do:

```
this.refs.titleInput.value
```

in `SubmitStoryForm.jsx`, but

```
this.refs.bodyInput.value
```

works fine.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use `refs` to give a parent access to data of a child component, you really shouldn't. (Netflix, a heavy user of react, even has a rule **"no refs, ever"** See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDARP5QZ6nU&index=28&list=PLb0IAmt7-GS0M8Q95RIc2lOM6nc77q1IY), from about 10m in). 
In 99.9% of all cases, anything that you can use `refs` for, can be solved better in some other way.
In your example, the parent should not need access to the child's data through refs:

- if the data is about child props, then the parent already knows about the data, and therefore: no refs needed.
- if the data is about child state, then using refs to access that data is really cheating react: state is not supposed to be directly accessible from outside the component.
- if the data is not in child props, nor in child state, then it probably is a design omission to be fixed, because data relevant to the app should be either props or state.

In your case, a better and `ref`-less solution would be:

- make your parent component stateful, by adding state for `textInputValue` and `textAreaValue`
- add a `onChange()` handler for textarea in your parent (since this component is directly rendered by the parent), which updates state
- pass `this.state.textInputValue` and a `changeHandler={this.textInputChangeHandler}` as props to your `<TextInput>` component
- in your `<TextInput>` component, add an `onChange={this.props.changeHandler}` to the input component, which calls the method on the parent to update state
- in the change handlers in your parent, you can read `event.target.value` to get the new value of the fields.

By doing this, you put the input values into state in the parent, and pass one of them as props to the child.

Bonus: in any code to submit your form, you do not need to read all fields again. You can simply get all info from `this.state` to send to wherever.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for. That couldn't have been the correct way.