# React - state is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

**What I'm trying to achieve**: Pass data from child to parent.

**How I'm trying to achieve it:** Using `this.state` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286356/meteor-get-value-from-child-to-parent/37286916#37286916)

Not sure how to word the title: When I `console.log(this.state)` in the function in which I modify the state, the correct values in `this.state` are printed out. However, when I try to read the state in another function, `this.state` is apparently still at empty values.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titleInputValue: "",
    };
}

<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
    <TextInput
        val={this.state.titleInputValue}
        changeHandler={this.textInputChangeHandler} />
</form>


// This is the function which can apparently only get the initial state
// title and body are empty strings, they should have values
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const title = this.state.titleInputValue;
    const body = this.state.bodyInputValue;
    console.log(this.state);
    Meteor.call('stories.insert',title,body);
}

// However, here the state is retrieved just fine.
// This is the function the child calls to update the state.
textInputChangeHandler(event) {
    // This console.log call shows the correct state!
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({
      titleInputValue: event.target.value,
    });
}
```

`TextInput` has attribute `onChange={this.props.changeHandler.bind(this)}`

For illustration:

[image]

I wrote `asd`, and the state was successfully retrieved in `textInputChangeHandler`, which is the first two `console.log` calls, but then it's empty in `handleSubmit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the event handler scope is not Component class level. When your component handles the event, it's context is the component (in your case TextInput ) not the parent.

You have to bind that function to this of Component class scope:

```
<TextInput
        val={this.state.titleInputValue}
        changeHandler={this.textInputChangeHandler.bind(this) } />
```

Using JavaScript bind you can specify the function context as well.

Comment: Thank you sir, it works now! I will mark your answer as correct as soon as it is available

Comment: @Gudmundur I'm very glad to hear that.